# Consulta para pegar texto apos determinado caractere

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia, Preciso de uma forma para pegar todo o restante de uma string apos determinado caractere, por exemplo, tenho a seguinte base de dados 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso buscar sempre o que resta da string apos o ultimo **"»"** ou seja, para a primeira linha eu precisava pegar todo **"Acesso ao sistema" pois não tem "»"**

Na segunda row preciso pegar **APENAS "Farmácia Popular"** pois está apos o o ULTIMO "»"

Até o momento tenho a seguinte query

```
select TOP 10 COUNT(SolID) as soma, SolCaminho as caminho
from Solicitacao where
DATEPART(m, SolData) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolData) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
and UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao = 2655
group by SolCaminho order by soma desc
```

Tentei fazer com SUBSTRING com CharIndex porém não tive sucesso.
Já postei essa pergunta aqui a algum tempo porém não obtive resultado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode conseguir a posição da última ocorrência de `>>` usando a função `LOCATE` em conjunto com a `REVERSE` e após isso utilizar a quantidade de caracteres encontrada neste resultado para retornar os caracteres a direita, usando `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT CASE x.posicao
         WHEN 0 THEN x.solcaminho
         else RIGHT(x.solcaminho, x.posicao - 1)
       END AS solcaminho
  FROM (SELECT *,
               LOCATE(' >> ', REVERSE(s.solcaminho)) AS posicao
          FROM solicitacao s) x
```

Aqui você confere o [**SQL Fiddler com a proposta funcionando**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4e7b/11).

Answer (score -1):

Depois que fizer a consulta você pode fazer esse tratamento, antes de retorna o resultado da consulta para a grid ou outro elemento que estiver usando, só pegar o código e jogar dentro de um arquivo PHP e fazer o teste.

```
// aqui é o campo caminho que vai retornar da consulta.

$caminho ="Faturamento>>Cupom>>Add";
echo "Caminho a ser quebrado<br>".$caminho;
$string = explode('>>', $caminho);

echo "<br>String quebrada<br>";
echo "<pre>";// echo pre

print_r($string);
$s = (count($string))==1?'0':count($string)-1;

echo "vou imprimir so a ultima parte do caminho ".$string[$s];
```