# Imprimindo uma String até ser encontrado um espaço

Tags: php, string

Recebo uma String através de uma input e faço a inserção no banco de dados. Quando vou listar, quero apenas o primeiro nome da pessoa, ou seja, até que seja encontrado o primeiro espaço. Existe alguma função que faça isso?

Comment: Sim é possível! :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pode usar a função [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) pois ela retona apenas a primeira parte daquela string. Por padrão o valor retornado está a direita do limitador. Para mudar isso ou seja pegar o valor a esquerda informe `true` no terceiro argumento(`$befero_needle`)

```
$str = "João da Silva Sauro";
echo strstr($str, ' ', true);
```

Saída:

```
João
```

---

Sobre o [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) nenhuma das respostas comentou que a partir do php5.4 é possível retornar o índice desejado já na chamada da função.

```
$str = "João da Silva Sauro";
echo explode(' ', $str)[0];
```

Comment: Muito bom, rray! Obrigado :D

Comment: Ingratos, esqueceram da `strtok` \0.0/

Comment: No 5.4 já dá pra fazer isso? achei que era no 5.5

Answer (score 16):

**Exemplo**:

```
$nome_completo = "Ciclano Fulano";
$palavras = explode(" ", $nome_completo);
$primeiro_nome = $palavras[0];

print_r($primeiro_nome);
```

**Resultado**:

Ciclano

Answer (score 15):

Pode ser da seguinte forma:

```
$string = "Nome Completo";
$string = explode(" ", $string);
echo $string[0];
```

Neste caso, aparecerá apenas "nome"

Answer (score 15):

Outro modo:

```
$str = 'John Doe';

echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str.' ', ' '));
```

Answer (score 12):

Sim, só usar esse exemplo:

```
// aqui é o campo caminho que vai retornar da consulta.

$caminho ="Faturamento Cupom";
echo "Caminho a ser quebrado<br>".$caminho;
$string = explode(' ', $caminho);

echo "vou imprimir só a primeira parte do caminho ".$string[0];
```

para imprimir a ultima parte https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97629/35597

Answer (score 12):

Uma das muitas formas é essa

```
$nome = 'João da Silva';
echo preg_replace("#^([^\s]*)\s.*?$#", "$1", $nome); // Exibe João

$nome = 'José';
echo preg_replace("#^([^\s]*)\s.*?$#", "$1", $nome); // Exibe José
```

Answer (score 5):

Aí ela pode ficar magoada :'(

Esqueceram de mencionar a função (não tão conhecida) `strtok`.

Veja aí:

```
$nome = 'Wallace de Souza Vizerra';

echo strtok($nome, ' ')
```

A saída será:

```
"Wallace"
```

Outro exemplo é que, em versões superiores ao PHP 5.4, você não precisa mais de atribuir uma variável ao `explode` para depois imprimir o indice `0`.
 Basta apenas fazer:

```
$nome = "wallace de souza";
echo explode(' ', $nome)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro limpe os espaços em branco à esquerda.

Depois, se for uma entrada de usuário, ele pode inserir "outros caracteres que não são espaços", tais como o caractere invisível, um ENTER ou um TAB. Ou pode ser que ele digite apenas o primeiro nome mesmo, então o uso de funções simples do PHP irão falhar. Utilize expressão regular. Segue o código:

```
<?php

// Sua string
$str = ' Márcio jalber';

// Limpa espaços em branco
$strLimpa = ltrim( $str, " \t\n" );

// Limpa a string
$strFinal = preg_replace( '/(.*?)[\n\t\s].*/', '\1', $strLimpa );
```

Comment: Expressão regular pra fazer uma coisa tão simples?

Comment: Realmente. Após analisar a pergunta vi que não se trata de uma entrada de usuário, mas de um valor que já existe no banco (e presumimos estar tratado). Então concordo em substituir a última linha pelo comando que mencionou em sua resposta `echo explode(' ', $nome)[0]`